# Do one have to wait after pressing "update" on a post edit page?

Tags: posts, post-editor

Do one have to wait after pressing "update" on a post edit page (becuase if he won't the post update process will be ruin) or does it make no difference what happens after one clicked the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to see the results, you don't have to wait (OTOH if you don't wait you will not be sure if it was actually sent, or maybe you had a wifi problem preventing it, unlikely event but does happen from time to time.)

Comment: Thanks. just to be sure i understand that: the process that his happening which is reflected by the cycling dot to the side of the update button isn't requiring the post edit page to be open. right?

Comment: @Ben, what cycling dot? but in general on all web forms, once you submit them, there is o way to prevent them from "executing". When it might happen you usually get a notice that tells you not to navigate away

Comment: actually that's not exactly true, because a form can execute a validation process before he sends the details or so...

Comment: @Ben Oh yes, there are all kinds of edge cases, but for most of them humans are not fast enough to close the window before they are actually over. The problems that I assume this question refer too (plugin upgrade?) arise with processes that take long time to complete on the server side, or when the connection is slow. There are more questions that I read about how to cancel a form submittion then should you wait for its completion